# UNIX - Determine Physical Device of specific File System

Tags: aix, storage

While trying to troubleshoot a possible I/O disk performance issue on AIX 7.2:

```
$ oslevel -r
7200-05

$ oslevel
7.2.0.0
```

I'm trying to understand how to identify the target device (iostat), without installing additional packages, as the AIX server has no access to the internet or local repository.

What I've learned so far:

`pwd -P` will show the physical directory:

```
$ cd /etc/opt/legacy/module/conf/tmpdir

$ pwd
/etc/opt/legacy/module/conf/tmpdir

$ pwd -P
/tmp
```

`df` will show the matching file system:

```
$ df | grep "/tmp"
/dev/hd3        31457280  30641296    3%      189     1% /tmp
```

Which from the above command output, turns out to be: `/dev/hd3`

`iostat` will show the input/output of **all** Devices:

```
System configuration: lcpu=16 drives=11 ent=1.00 paths=264 vdisks=0

tty:      tin         tout    avg-cpu: % user % sys % idle % iowait physc % entc
          0.2          8.4               10.9   4.6   84.1      0.4   0.4   41.4

Disks:         % tm_act     Kbps      tps    Kb_read   Kb_wrtn
hdisk1            0.0       0.0       0.0        754        56
hdisk0            0.0       0.0       0.0          0         0
hdisk17           0.0       0.1       0.0        774   1384212
hdisk16           0.0       0.0       0.0      54626    432704
hdisk18           0.0       0.0       0.0        754        56
hdisk9            0.0       0.1       0.0    1638802    461272
hdisk8            0.0       0.0       0.0      54750     19032
hdisk5            0.0       0.0       0.0       1142     28476
hdisk3            0.0       0.0       0.0          0         0
hdisk4            0.0       0.0       0.0      16840         0
hdisk2            0.0       0.0       0.0       4210    138592
```

And `iostat -Dl` will show the **all** devices response time (I/O):

```
$ iostat -Dl

System configuration: lcpu=16 drives=11 paths=264 vdisks=0

Disks:                      xfers                                read                                write                                  queue               
--------------- -------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------
                  %tm    bps   tps  bread  bwrtn   rps    avg    min    max time fail   wps    avg    min    max time fail    avg    min    max   avg   avg  serv
                  act                                    serv   serv   serv outs              serv   serv   serv outs        time   time   time  wqsz  sqsz qfull
hdisk1            0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0   4.4    0.4   21.7     0    0   0.0   1.7    1.2    6.0     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk0            0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0    0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk17           0.0  66.0    0.0   0.0   66.0    0.0   1.4    0.2    4.8     0    0   0.0   3.6    1.3   16.3     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk16           0.0  31.7    0.0   5.4   26.3    0.0   1.1    0.2   14.4     0    0   0.0   2.3    1.1   18.6     0    0   0.6    0.0   20.8    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk18           0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0   2.6    0.3   11.7     0    0   0.0   1.9    1.2    7.2     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk9            0.0 121.0    0.0  94.1   26.9    0.0   0.9    0.2   22.3     0    0   0.0   1.9    1.1   14.3     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.1    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk8            0.0   7.7    0.0   6.3    1.4    0.0   0.8    0.2   27.5     0    0   0.0   2.0    1.1   13.8     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.1    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk5            0.0   3.0    0.0   0.1    2.9    0.0   1.3    0.2   12.0     0    0   0.0   1.7    1.1   16.7     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.1    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk3            0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0    0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk4            0.0   0.8    0.0   0.8    0.0    0.0   4.2    0.2   36.2     0    0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0     0    0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
hdisk2            0.0  16.5    0.0   0.2   16.3    0.0   4.8    0.3   34.0     0    0   0.0   1.8    1.1   19.2     0    0   0.1    0.0    5.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
$
```

How do I find the correct device (**hdisk**), that hosts the target file system: `/dev/hd3`?

Is this possible without installing additional packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `hdisk??` are physical disks and `hd??` are logical disks you need to execute:

```
lslv -l hd3
```

to get the physical disks where this LV is located. If you want to see physical partitions you can use:

```
lslv -m hd3
```

**Warning**: the last list can be quite long